# php laravel get data on pivot table that needs joining

Tags: php, laravel

I'm designing a system with database like this

Companies

```
id
name
```

Employees

```
id
name
```

company_employee

```
company_id
employee_id
employee_role
```

EmployeeRole

```
id
name
```

This is to let an employee can be under many companies, with different roles. 
Now, query

`App\Company::find(1)->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('employee_role')->get()`

I can get something like

```
App\Employee {#1183
         id: 7,
         name: "John Doe",
         avatar: null,
         salary: 20000,
         insurance: 4000,
         created_at: "2018-03-28 10:15:00",
         updated_at: "2018-04-06 03:56:48",
         user_id: null,
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#1172
           company_id: 1,
           employee_id: 7,
           employee_role: 3,


           },
       },
```

Take a look at the pivot property, I can get their role in that specific company, but I need the role name too ( like 'Manager', or 'Sales' ). I want something like :

```
App\Employee {#1183
         id: 7,
         name: "John Doe",
         avatar: null,
         salary: 20000,
         insurance: 4000,
         created_at: "2018-03-28 10:15:00",
         updated_at: "2018-04-06 03:56:48",
         user_id: null,
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#1172
           company_id: 1,
           employee_id: 7,
           employee_role: 3,
**employee_role_name: "Manager"**
         },
       },
```

How do I do this with Eloquent?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, by default your custom pivot column will not be appended to your query, the reason why because you need to specify which cols do you want to show.

Please try this within your employee model:

`return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class) ->withPivot('employee_role');`

Comment: I've edited my question for clarification. Please update your answer too. Thanks

Comment: what is `$c` because I am little confused about your code, but if you want to show the role name in the view you could do something like this `App\Role::find($c->employee_role)->name` all you need is to create `Role` model.

Comment: $c is App\Company instance. The problem with doing like you suggest is the n+1 problem. Imagine I have 2000 rows of employees, how heavy is it to the database ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a pivot model:

```
class YourPivotModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(EmployeeRole::class, 'employee_role');
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$c->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('employee_role')
    ->using(YourPivotModel::class)->get();
```

Then you can access the role name like this:

```
$employee->pivot->role->name
```

Comment: look like what i'm looking for. Let me try and get back. Thanks

Comment: any idea why i got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fromRawAttributes()"` when trying to  `dd($this->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('employee_role')->using(CompanyEmployee::class)->get());` ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that `YourPivotModel` has to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`.

Comment: it's working. But, it doesnt solve n+1 problem does it ? each time I query `$employee->pivot->role->name` , another query is added no ? Is there a way to eager load it ?

Comment: You can do it like this: `$employees->pluck('pivot')->load('role');`

Comment: That's basically pre-load roles right ? not really eager loading role name INTO `App\Company::find(1)->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('employee_role')->get()` query ? I get it, it works, just that we'll have to do extra steps. I guess we can do manual query, joining the pivot table ourselves, but Laravel doesnt support it out of the box

Comment: It's not ideal but I don't think there's a way to add the eager loading to the relationship query.

Comment: ok thanks anyway. At least i got confirmation it can't be done.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.